# My CSS content keeps moving vertically on my website?

Tags: html, css, frontend

So basically I am trying to make a search engine page. The hr does not want to align in the center. On top of that when I resize the page in height it sends the text in the middle and the search bar diagonally left. I am unsure what I am doing wrong. I find positioning in CSS so so hard.

I am unsure on if I am positioning correctly. I was trying to lock my content down by using vh and vw. However I have a lot of trouble locking everything down vertically.

Live Preview" https://codepen.io/thanksfortheride136/project/editor/DYaryO

```css
#indexbody {
  background-image: url("/school.jpg");
  background-size: 100% auto;
}

* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
}


/*controls size of logo link box*/

.logo a {
  display: block;
  height: auto;
}

li {
  list-style: none;
}


/* NAVBAR STYLING STARTS */

.navbar {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
  padding: 20px;
  background-color: #2f2e2e;
  color: #2f2e2e;
  font-family: 'Open Sans';
  z-index: 1;
}

.navbaratlus {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
  padding: 20px;
  background-color: transparent;
  color: #2f2e2e;
  font-family: 'Open Sans';
  z-index: 1;
}

.nav-links a {
  color: #fff;
}


/* LOGO */

.logo img {
  width: 230px;
  height: 75px;
}


/* NAVBAR MENU */

.menu {
  display: flex;
  gap: 1em;
  font-size: 20px;
  z-index: 1;
}

.menu li:hover {
  background-color: #1a1a1a;
  transition: 0.1.5s ease;
}


/*everytime i adjust sizing i usually need to adjust sizing on the dropdown menu too*/

.menu li {
  padding: 25px 24px;
  padding-left: 5px;
  border-left: 1px solid white;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 200px;
  z-index: 1;
}

.home {
  border-left: 1px solid white;
}


/* DROPDOWN MENU */

.classes {
  position: relative;
}

.dropdown {
  background-color: #1a1a1a;
  padding-top: 1em;
  position: absolute;
  /*WITH RESPECT TO PARENT*/
  display: none;
  top: 70px;
}

.dropdown li+li {
  margin-top: 10px;
}

.dropdown li {
  padding: 0.5em 1em;
  width: 8em;
}

.dropdown li:hover {
  background-color: #2f2e2e;
  width: 100%;
}

.classes:hover .dropdown {
  display: block;
}


/*RESPONSIVE NAVBAR MENU STARTS*/


/* CHECKBOX HACK */

input[type=checkbox] {
  display: none;
}


/*HAMBURGER MENU*/

.hamburger {
  display: none;
  font-size: 24px;
  user-select: none;
}


/* APPLYING MEDIA QUERIES */

@media (max-width: 768px) {
  .menu {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: teal;
    right: 0;
    left: 0;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 16px 0;
  }
  .menu li:hover {
    display: inline-block;
    background-color: #4c9e9e;
    transition: 0.3s ease;
  }
  .menu li+li {
    margin-top: 12px;
  }
  input[type=checkbox]:checked~.menu {
    display: block;
  }
  .hamburger {
    display: block;
  }
  .dropdown {
    left: 50%;
    top: 30px;
    transform: translateX(35%);
  }
  .dropdown li:hover {
    background-color: #4c9e9e;
  }
}

.footercontainer {
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 20px;
  background-color: #2f2e2e;
  border: 5px solid green;
}

.atlasbar[type=text] {
  padding: 6px;
  font-size: 17px;
  font-family: 'open sans';
  color: white;
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  height: 40px;
  width: 35%;
  z-index: 1;
  top: 30vh;
  left: 50vh;
  right: 50vh;
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 50px #000, /* inner color*/
  inset 20px 0 80px #000, /* inner left short*/
  inset -20px 0 80px #0ff, /* inner right short*/
  inset 20px 0 300px #f0f, /* inner left broad*/
  inset -20px 0 300px #0ff, /* inner right broad*/
  0 0 10px #fff, /* outer color*/
  -1px 0 10px #f0f, /* out left color*/
  1px 0 10px #0ff;  /* outer right color*/
}

 ::placeholder {
  color: white;
}

.atlascontainer {
  display: block;
  height: 35vh;
  width: 100vw;
  position: absolute;
  border: 1px solid red;
}

.title {
  font-family: 'Akshar', sans-serif;
  color: white;
  font-size: 100px;
  text-align: center;
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  width: 35%;
  z-index: 1;
  top: 10vh;
  left: 50vh;
  right: 50vh;
}

hr {
  color: white;
  display: block;
  z-index: 1;
  margin-top: 27vh;
  margin-left: 50vw;
  margin-right: 50vw;
  width: 30%;
  position: absolute;
}

p {
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  width: 35%;
  top: 23vh;
  left: 50vh;
  right: 50vh;
  z-index: 1;
}

.atlasimage {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  width: 50%;
  height: 100%;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  z-index: -1;
}

body {
  height: 100vh;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Open+Sans:wght@300&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Akshar&family=Open+Sans:wght@300&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
  <nav class="navbaratlus">
    <!-- LOGO -->
    <div class="logo">
      <a href='/index.html'><img src="logospaced.png" alt=""></a>
    </div>
    <!-- NAVIGATION MENU -->
    <ul class="nav-links">
      <!-- USING CHECKBOX HACK -->
      <input type="checkbox" id="checkbox_toggle" />
      <label for="checkbox_toggle" class="hamburger">&#9776;</label>

      <!-- NAVIGATION MENUS -->
      <div class="menu">
        <li class='home'><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
        <li class="classes"><a href="classes.html">Classes</a>
          <!-- DROPDOWN MENU -->
          <ul class="dropdown">
            <li><a href="/">AP CS</a></li>
            <li><a href="/">STEM</a></li>
            <li><a href="/">Media Arts</a></li>
            <li> <a href="/">Physics</a></li>
            <li><a href="/">Tech 8</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="atlas.html">Atlas</a></li>
        <li><a href="curriculum.html">Curriculum</a></li>
        <li><a href="/">Contact</a></li>
      </div>
    </ul>
  </nav>

  <div class='atlascontainer'>
    <input type="text" placeholder="Search.." class="atlasbar">
    <h1 class='title'>ATLAS</h1>
    <p>A Technology Learning Aid System</p>
    <hr>
  </div>

  <img src="editedatlas.png" alt="" class='atlasimage'>
  <div class='footercontainer'></div>
```